# How to nest multiple span tags. Everything I have found is either outdated or convoluted

Tags: html, css

I would like **"header to be smaller and aligned to the left of "MainHtml"**.

Is span even the best way to do this?
Any and all critiques would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles0.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MainHtml</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<span style="color:white;">header</span>MainHtml</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

"header" is already to the left of "MainHtml", so all you would need to do is add "font-size:*n*;" Where *n* is a font-size smaller than "MainHtml".

An example would be to have:

```html
<header style="font-size:48px;">
  <span style="font-size:30px;color:white;">header</span>MainHtml
</header>
```

I hope this is what you are after. My first post, so I'm trying :).

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, my issue was I was trying 1em, it was the same size.  Just had to use .5